# Does aluminium in deodorants cause cancer?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine

I have read that the claim that deodorants with aluminium cause breast-cancer is false. But here is an [article](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2011/10/17/aluminum-containing-antiperspirants-contribute-breast-cancer.aspx) talking about the dangers

> Your antiperspirant probably contains aluminum, and that aluminum may be absorbed into your breast tissue where it could potentially increase your risk of breast cancer or other health problems

Does aluminium in deodorants cause cancer?

Comment: I've cleaned up the question a bit. I know that it's slightly different from the original, however it _is_ about the claim you posted as required. There are no other major claims on that page.

Comment: As a general rule, whatever Mercola claims, the opposite is probably true.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Breast cancer causes aluminum deodorant cans?